# Leveraging Ember with Enyo?

Tags: ember.js, enyo

I am starting to evaluate frameworks for a HTML5 app.  I really like the enyo model for developing an app.  However, my app needs an object-relational mapper (ORM) for local storage and some way to update the UI based on changes in the ORM data.

It looks like Ember has some great linkages for the ORM and update parts.

Has anyone used these two together?  Does it makes sense or do either of them (by themselves) already address the entire problem space?

Thanks in advance,

Charlie

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried to integrate them directly yet, but I think that the Enyo event model would work well here.  Have the ORM live as a top-level component in your application and have it broadcast data change messages into your tree of components using enyo.waterfall() or enyo.waterfallDown().

I do something similar in a cryptogram game I'm working on where I use that mechanism to broadcast information about the player's guesses into the view tree where individual cells use them to modify their display.